Firebase send multiple notification in push notification
I am facing a problem: when my application is in the foreground position, then a notification comes one time, but when my application is in background mode, then a notification comes two or three times. Can you please review my code and detect my error, please?
Here is my code.
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import PushNotification, {Importance} from 'react-native-push-notification';
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';

function App(): React.JSX.Element {
  const [token, setToken] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const backgroundStyle = {
    backgroundColor: 'black',
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    // Create notification channel
    PushNotification.createChannel(
      {
        channelId: 'channel-id',
        channelName: 'My channel',
        channelDescription: 'A channel to categorise your notifications',
        playSound: true,
        soundName: 'custom_sound_2.mp3',
        importance: Importance.HIGH,
        vibrate: false,
      },
      () => console.log('Notification channel created'),
    );

    // Configure PushNotification
    PushNotification.configure({
      onNotification: function (notification) {
        console.log('Local Notification:', notification);
      },
      popInitialNotification: true,
      requestPermissions: true,
    });

    // Request Firebase notification permission
    const requestPermission = async () => {
      const authStatus = await messaging().requestPermission();
      const enabled =
        authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED ||
        authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.PROVISIONAL;

      if (enabled) {
        console.log('Authorization status:', authStatus);
      }
    };

    requestPermission();

    // Get FCM token
    messaging()
      .getToken()
      .then(fcmToken => {
        console.log('FCM Token:', fcmToken);
        setToken(fcmToken);
      });

    // Foreground notification handler
    const unsubscribeOnMessage = messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage => {
      console.log('Foreground Notification:', remoteMessage);

      PushNotification.localNotification({
        message: remoteMessage.notification?.body ?? 'No message body',
        channelId: 'channel-id',
        playSound: true,
        soundName: 'custom_sound_2.mp3',
        importance: 'high',
        vibrate: false,
        title: remoteMessage.notification?.title ?? 'No Title',
      });
    });

    const handleBackgroundNotification = async (remoteMessage: any) => {
      console.log('Background Notification:', remoteMessage);

      PushNotification.localNotification({
        message: remoteMessage.notification?.body ?? 'No message body',
        channelId: 'channel-id',
        playSound: true,
        soundName: 'custom_sound_2.mp3',
        importance: 'high',
        vibrate: false,
        title: remoteMessage.notification?.title ?? 'No Title',
      });
    };

    // Background notification handler
    messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(handleBackgroundNotification);

    return () => {
      unsubscribeOnMessage();
    };
  }, []);
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={style.container}>
      <StatusBar
        barStyle={'light-content'}
        backgroundColor={backgroundStyle.backgroundColor}
      />
      <ScrollView contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic">
        <View style={style.main}>
          <Text style={style.text}>Hello From React native</Text>
          {/* <Button title="Get Notification" onPress={handlePressNotification} /> */}
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
const style = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  main: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  text: {
    color: 'black',
  },
});
export default App;

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml file also.
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
      android:supportsRtl="true">
       <!-- Change the value to true to enable pop-up for in foreground on receiving remote notifications (for prevent duplicating while showing local notifications set this to false) -->
      <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_foreground"
                    android:value="false"/>
      <!-- Change the resource name to your App's accent color - or any other color you want -->
      <!-- <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_color"
                    android:resource="@color/white"/> or @android:color/{name} to use a standard color -->
      <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationActions" android:exported="false" />
      <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationPublisher" android:exported="false" />
      <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationBootEventReceiver" android:exported="false">   
          <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
            </intent-filter>
      </receiver>
      <service
            android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationListenerService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>            
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>


For getting notifications, I am using the react-native-push-notification library.
Please help me to resolve this error.
